# How do I prevent window drafts?

Tags: insulation, energy-efficiency, windows

I live in Florida. I have noticed that in the Winter it seems that the cold air leaks through the windows and into the rooms. This, of course, raises my energy bill for heating (yes we have to turn on the heat in Florida sometimes!)

It seems like to me that the air is leaking through where the bottom of the window meets the aluminum frame.

I thought that I could use [window frame weather stripping](http://www.lowes.com/pd_127947-81-63669_0_?productId=1010043&Ntt=weather+stripping&Ntk=i_products&pl=1&currentURL=/pl__0__s?newSearch=true%24Ntt=weather%20stripping%24y=0%24x=0) to place between where the window comes down to meet the frame and the frame itself. So essentially, the window would "squish" the insulation and make a good seal.

Is this the preferred method? I have checked the caulking in and around the window. It is definitely not leaking through there and in the Winter I can feel the cold air come through the sill.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding that EPDM weather stripping will help if the leak is between the sash and the window sill.  I actually had a piece of that stuff in my car to stop a door frame air leak for many years.

I would also check to make sure the air isn't leaking between the sashes of the window as well.

Once you put the weather strip in place, I would go back and double check the perimeter of the window frame for leaks using the old candle test to check for any drafts.

Additionally - Aluminum windows are notorious heat transmitters (they let in lots of heat from outside in summer and cold in winter).  I've noticed on cold days aluminum window frames can be so cold relative to inside it almost feels like a slight draft due to convection or whatever effect is in place there.

One more overlooked spot you may want to look at to seal up is your electrical outlets - they are responsible for leaking a lot of air as well.  You can get gaskets which go on underneath the cover plates that will seal that leakage up.

Good luck!

Comment: I have seen the gaskets at Lowes. Do you recommend them? They are pricey.

Comment: I think anywhere you can seal a potential air leak to/from the outside it's worth the cost.  However, DON'T buy that stuff from home improvement stores - you are getting hosed on price.  There are many online retailers that sell that stuff super cheap.  http://www.reducemyenergy.com/store/draftproducts.asp?cat=1 for example.